# Android development problems with xml and positioning of imageviews

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Android dev newbie here! Creating a football-based game with a start button, a clickable ball image and then 3 targets to aim for at the top of the screen layout. I have two problems with my XML positioning. Firstly, the 3 targets are placed on top of each other and are not to the right/left of the centre target. Secondly, the ball image is directly below the targets but I want a big space between ball and targets to aim at, how do I go about creating the space?

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/green"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/target1"
        android:src="@drawable/t1_box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/target2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/t2_box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/target3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/t3_box" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/football_only"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/football_only"
    android:src="@drawable/blue_football"
    android:clickable="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startCountdownButton"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:text="@string/start" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATED:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/green"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/target1"
        android:src="@drawable/t1_box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/target2"
        android:src="@drawable/t2_box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/target3"
        android:src="@drawable/t3_box" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/football_only"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/football_only"
    android:src="@drawable/blue_football" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startCountdownButton"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:text="@string/start" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the 3 targets are placed on top of each other and are not to the right/left of the centre target.

This is because their parent is a `RelativeLayout` so by default they are placed at the top-left of their parent. You can use properties such as `android:layout_alightToRightOf="@id/someid"`. But you probably just want to change that `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout` then they will be placed left-to-right.

> Secondly, the ball image is directly below the targets but I want a big space between ball and targets to aim at, how do I go about creating the space?

You can add an empty `<View>` between them to add space and give it whatever `height` you need. You also could use `margin` on either the ball or the `ViewGroup` which holds your `ImageView`s.

Something like

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/football_only"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:contentDescription="@string/football_only"
android:src="@drawable/blue_football"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />   // here change it to whatever you need.
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about the space between ball/targets but having changed to LinearLayout still same result of targets all on top of each other. Also with LinearLayout the only to left/right of option is android:layout_marginLeft??

Comment: I would have to see your updated xml to say for sure. I don't know what you mean by "left/right of option". You don't need this in a horizontal `LinearLayout` because they are placed left-to-right by default. You can use `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginRight` to create space in between them. Or you can use an empty `View` there also. With these types of questions, pictures are great (what you want and what you have) when possible.

Comment: You also should consider accepting answers when you find some that are helpful...it will be more likely for you to get help in the future. You have 6 questions and 0 accepts

Comment: @smoggers I fully agree with codeMagic here. What prevents you from clicking that check-icon next to the questions?

Comment: a solution would receive a tick

Comment: @smoggers I'm not talking so much about mine but the others you have open.

Comment: Your child `LinearLayout` has a vertical `orientation`. Remove that so they will lay out horizontally.

Comment: I am upvoting now, since @smoggers seems to forget it :-P

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the attributes:

```
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/t1"
```

and

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/t1"
```

to align those specific images to the left or right of the image in the middle.

Please note that for this you need a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Im not seeing the layout_toLeftOf with LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes it is for `RelativeLayout` only. What prevents you from using RelativeLayout? ;-) @smoggers

Comment: The other guy said that was the problem so should change to Linear from Relative

Comment: I didn't necessarily say that is the problem. I said you could do it with `RelativeLayout` using these properties but that it may be easier with a `LinearLayout`. I was explaining that without additional properties, `RelativeLayout` puts all of it's children in the top-left(they get sent to the corner for not having properties)